# Read Json Kafka message without schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

Currently we are working on a real time data feeds having Json data.

While reading the examples from -
https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-streaming-with-kafka/

It looks like we need a schema for kafka json message.

Is there any other way to process data without schema ?

Comment: What kind of processing do you want to perform without a schema?

Comment: Copy Entire data AS IS to Cloud Storage for now.

Comment: The data is in the Value field as a string. There you have the data from the topic

Comment: The Value field is binary from the topic. we need to deserialize it and it requires schema to deserialize.

Comment: Not necessarily you just need to convert value part in string and then writestrem into  destination location

Comment: Thanks, This helps to save the json in single column called value. How to extract data from fields inside json without writing to destination location ?

Answer (score 2):

try below code after running the zookeeper, Kafka server and other required service.

```
df = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
        .option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name) \
        .option("startingOffsets", "latest")\
        .load()  #earliest

print("Printing Schema of transaction_detail_df: ")
df.printSchema()

transaction_detail_df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

trans_detail_write_stream = transaction_detail_df1 \
    .writeStream \
    .trigger(processingTime='2 seconds') \
    .option("truncate", "false") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

trans_detail_write_stream.awaitTermination()
```

just change the basic configuration, you would be able to see the output

Comment: Thanks, This helps to save the json in single column called value. How to extract data from fields inside json ?

Comment: You can explode the dataframe columns based on requirement

Comment: Thanks, This worked with work around. 
Since saving the json value this way makes the schema as single string column where 'explode' cannot be applied. However writing as intermediate file as text and reading as json worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_json_object`  SparkSQL function to parse data out of JSON string data without defining any additional schema.

You can simply use `cast` function to deserialize the binary key/value, as the example shows